# Is this ironic? and if not what is it called?

Tags: irony, poetic

Someone is so fat they cant bend down to pick up a bag of food that lies at their feet and then as a result end up dying of starvation

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Hi Tyler, it's important to look up a dictionary before you ask this kind of question here, as it will often provide the solution. Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Your example is also tasteless in the extreme, needlessly hurtful to people who struggle with their weight, and somewhat ridiculous from a medical point of view. It's also likely in breach of our [Code of Conduct](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct) - I recommend you [edit] your post to use a different example.

Comment: I didnt mean to be rude or offend! After looking up the definition me and a friend of mine were still in disagreement on the example.

Comment: Related: 1. [What word means what many people think 'ironic' means?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6618/what-word-means-what-many-people-think-ironic-means) 2. [Is this an example of irony?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28419/is-this-an-example-of-irony)

Comment: A better example is the old story of the donkey halfway between two sources of food, who starved because he couldn't decide which to go for first.

Comment: @Kate Buridan's ass?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, I think your example is *ironic*:

> a situation in which something which was intended to have a particular result has the opposite or a very different result

Source: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/irony)

Ironies can also be funny. In your case, one might think that a person who is hungry can pick up a bag of food on the floor and feed themselves. But in your story, the *opposite* happened: the fat person ended up dying of starvation. (This can be a kind of dark humor!)